# How to save xlsm as xlsx?

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx

I have a xslm file. I want to save the file as xlsx and email.

I am able to SaveCopyAs it as xls file. If I try to save it as xlsx, it does get saved but when I open it, it gives an error.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyFileName - " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"
```

> Excel cannot open the file '...path\MyFileName.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that file has not been corrupted and that file extension matches the format of the file

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have VBA macros in the file, you cannot use the extension XLSX.

Comment: @braX you can, but after reopen, all macros are gone.

Answer (score 1):

`SaveCopyAs` does not change the file-type.

You simply cannot save a .xlsm as .xlsx via `SaveCopyAs`.

**EDIT**

a workaround is to save a copy which then is changed in type while the old copy will be deleted like:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, pstr As String

pstr = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyFileName - " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=y

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(pstr)
wb.SaveAs Left(pstr, Len(pstr) - 1) & "x", 52
wb.Close False

Kill pstr
```

Comment: How does it allow to savecopyas xls and not xlsx? Please guide if there is a way to save this file as xlsx since users are expecting it as xlsx

Comment: I am ok to use SaveAs if that is possible

Comment: @SilverFish `SaveCopyAs` does not change the file-type at all... (it can not) ;)

Comment: I can manually open the xslm file and do a file save as Excel Workbook xlsx. It does prompt that it will save it as macro free workbook. but that is fine. since we have to email it to users and macros are not needed. So you are saying that is not possible programmatically?

Comment: @SilverFish just use `SaveAs` instead of `SaveCopyAs` - then pass it the parameter for `.xlsx` You can also ignore the popup warning using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel

Comment: @SilverFish Instead of using `Kill` like in this example, just `Save` it once - then `SaveAs` using `.xlsx` and you will have both files - I will post an answer in a second - not sure why this is being overcomplicated

Comment: @user1274820 because we just know 1 line... there may be more lines to automatically send an email or whatever... doing it like that, is like the  `SaveCopyAs` worked as desired so no change in later parts of the code is needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub SaveAsXLSX()
ThisWorkbook.Save   'Optional
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyFileName - " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy"), 51 '51 = xlsx
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Close  'Optional
End Sub
```

All you need to do is `SaveAs` and change the file format to `51` (`xlsx`)

If you want to "Save a copy" - `SaveAs` does practically the same thing - the difference being your currently open file becomes the saved file, but you can simply reopen the old one if you wish and nothing changes.

What you actually want to do is `SaveAs` a different file type, so use `SaveAs`.

Comment: Keep in mind that execution of macros can get complicated as the `SaveAs` sets the new file to the actual.... this way `ThisWorkbook` changes at runtime... If you are working at your workbook and just going to send a copy, keep in mind to close the workbook and reopen the original one.

Comment: @DirkReichel it still closes the workbook, so it appears that the macro will finish running, though it is not "saved" in the new file.

Comment: Was just for the case of working with some kind of master workbook which will create a non-macro copy for sending while still working with the master afterwards... in that case the OP need to reopen the master file... still, as said: we just see that one line so I mainly "guess" this part (as it is the way I do my work with most files so I do not need to search every time for the most recent one)

Answer (score 0):

I This is more readable. TESTED.

```
 Sub SaveXlsmAsXlsx() 
Dim wb As Workbook, Filenamepath As String, Filenameext As String, Filenameonly As String, Filepathonly As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Filenamepath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Filenameext = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Filenameonly = Replace(Filenameext, ".xlsm", "")
Filepathonly = Replace(Filenamepath, ".xlsm", "")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filenamepath)
'51 = xlsx
wb.SaveAs Filename:=Filepathonly & "_" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy"), FileFormat:=51
wb.Close True
'Kill- Best not to kill anyone, you might be sorry
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. This code add to any module:

```
Public Sub XLSMtoXLSX(FaylAdi As String)
Dim FullPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook

MsgBox "YOU WILL GET A WARNING AFTER COMPLETED, PLEASE WAIT"

ThisWorkbook.Save

On Error GoTo XETA

'You can change the name of the folder path below
FullPath = "C:\kohne sistem\Excel\VBA\Anbar\temp\" & FaylAdi & ".xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FullPath

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FullPath)
wb.SaveAs Left(FullPath, Len(FullPath) - 1) & "x", 51
wb.Close False
Kill FullPath
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox "COMPLETED CORRECTLY"
Exit Sub
XETA: MsgBox "THERE WAS A FAULT SOMEWHERE"
End Sub
```

> 2. Then you can use it like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call XLSMtoXLSX(Date)
End Sub
```