# How do I save an XLSM file as an XLSX file without prompting the user about lost data?

Tags: excel, vba

*TLDR*:

How do I save a Excel-File-with-Macros as an Excel-File-without-Macros using VBA **suppressing the prompt that the target format does not support macros**?

---

I have a xlsb file (Excel 2007+ with Macros), inside is the content and a button that should save that file as an xlsx (Excel 2007 WITHOUT Macros). So far, so good. I'll use `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=name, FileFormat=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password="xyz"`

*But that always generates a prompt that tells the user that saving data in the target format means loosing the macro data and if he/she wants to continue...*

I've tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False`. I've also recorded the same action with the MacroRecorder that also seems unable to skip the upcoming prompt.

My last try was a copy of the content using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy` and trying to remove the VBProject data. Tried various ways but it seems that the vb-project data can't be really removed. After executing remove and stuff like that the debugger shows always three items of vb-project-data.

I'll check this tomorrow, but it looks very much like the code I've tried...
[Macro to save active Sheet as new workbook, ask user for location and remove macros from the new workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680875/macro-to-save-active-sheet-as-new-workbook-ask-user-for-location-and-remove-macr)

Comment: `Application.SaveAs` ?? Are you not using `Workbook.SaveAs`?

Comment: You're right. I think it was `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`. Don't remember the code exactly and can't access it from home

Comment: With `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` I don't have the confirmation dialog. (Excel 2010 here)

Comment: For some reason my code from yesterday was gone this morning. I've recreated it with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` and now it works. Very strange :/ Thx for your help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

`Thisworkbook.SaveCopyAs ([filename.xlsx])`.

This creates a copy of the workbook without the macros in it and without the alert. [filename.xlsx] should of course be replaced by your own file path. Use the xlsx extension to make sure you don't copy the macros.

Comment: This works too, but since I need to password-protect the new file I'll have to use `.SaveAs` combined with `.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't use `SaveCopyAs` and change the extension. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46432972/9245853